# Installing a wireless remote switch for a ceiling fan in an existing single gang box

Tags: wiring, switch, ceiling-fan

I installed a ceiling fan that has a wireless remote switch to control the light and fan speeds.  It can be mounted in the wall in an existing single gang box.  However the power to the fan must now be permanently on.  To do this I am assuming that I just need to use a wire nut to  connect the two black wires that go into the existing switch.  I.e., remove the existing switch, connect the two wires going in to the switch, and then mount the remote switch  in the existing gang box.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that will do it. Just remember to turn off the breaker and test wires to make sure they are not energized.